# Login/Logout Button Filter

Tags: wordpress

I have the following code to add a login/logout filter in the WP Nav Menu.

I would like to adapt this to be used on a Ultimate Addons for Elementor 'Multi Button' option, whereby the button will display Login or Logout dependent on the filter argument.

Is this possible, and if so could you advise on what needs to be amended within the code?

```
<?php
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'ia_custom_menu_item', 10, 2);
function ia_custom_menu_item($items, $args)
{
    //var_dump($args);
    if ($args->menu_id == 'top-menu') {
        if (is_user_logged_in()) {
            $items .= '<li id="menu-item-logout" class="menu-item menu-item-    logout"><a href="' . wp_logout_url() . '">Logout</a></li>';
        } else {
            $items .= '<li id="menu-item-login" class="menu-item menu-item-login"><a href="' . wp_login_url() . '">Login</a></li>';
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the Header menu for log-in and log-out users, create two menu and change the menu in header.php based on session value. refer below,

```
function sf_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {

    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
       $args['menu'] = 'logged-in';
     } else {
       $args['menu'] = 'logged-out';
     }
    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'sf_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

Or else you can directly add this li in header.php after main menu. Like below,

```
if( is_user_logged_in() ) {

           echo '<li id="menu-item-logout" class="menu-item menu-item-logout"><a href="'.wp_logout_url().'">Logout</a></li>';

   } else {

           echo '<li id="menu-item-login" class="menu-item menu-item-login"><a href="'. wp_login_url().'">Login</a></li>';

   }
```